# Symfony 4, Cannot instantiate abstract class App\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator. Guard

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am following this [tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-symfony-app-and-adding-authentication/) about authentication

I have a custom security class called FormLoginAuthenticator.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

abstract class FormLoginAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
protected $router;
protected $enconder;
public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
{
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->encoder = $encoder;
}
}
```

which extends the AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator from the symfony guard component which itself is a abstract class. 
However I keep gettting

```
Cannot instantiate abstract class App\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator
```

I have read about extending abstract classes and if my custom class has more than 1 abstract method I should use prefix the class keyword with `abstract. However I get that error when I added the abstract keyword. How to get around this problem

Comment: Somewhere, new FormLoginAuthenticator() is called, which is wrong because you defined it as abstract. To get rid of this, do not mark FormLoginAuthenticator as abstract and implement abstract methods of parent class AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator

Comment: @Med Thank you, would you be able to throw an example for me.

Comment: Just drop the word abstract from "abstract class FormLoginAuthenticator"

Answer (score 1):

You don't have abstract method in your

> FormLoginAuthenticator

, so this class shouldn't be abstract. The only abstract method is from its parent, but when you extend abstract parent, you don't define your new class as Abstract, unless there is next child, which is extending it. You can't instantiate abstract classes, thats where your error comes from. You have to define your class as normal or final
Small example here - https://3v4l.org/4MQpU#v560

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the keyword 'abstract' and implement abtract methods from parent class:

```
class LoginFormAuthenticator  extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator 
{
 ...
    protected function getLoginUrl(): string 
    {
        return $this->router->generate('login');
    }
 ...
}
```

And you are done.

Comment: Note: I have injected a RouterInterface in my example, so I can implement the 'getLoginUrl' method. You can do the same or choose another way to specify the login url : e.g return '/login' can be also a starting solution.

Answer (score 0):

As required, a small example.

From symfony github https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Guard/Authenticator/AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator.php, you should at least implement this function

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;

class ExampleFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    /**
     * Return the URL to the login page.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getLoginUrl(){
        // [TODO: implement]
    }

}
```